# Is there an equivalent to ( (ptr + i)->marks ), like ( ptr[i] .... )?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, indexing

I want to do something similar to the code below but using `ptr[i]`

```
printf("%s\t%d\n", (ptr + i)->subject, (ptr + i)->marks);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What happened when you tried it? Hint: `ptr+i` is still a pointer, while `ptr[i]` already dereferences the address and is of type depending on your pointer type.

Comment: Please only tag the language you are using unless you want to mix C and C++ in your project. While there are parts that are same in both languages, they are very different in other parts.

Comment: I'm assuming you already tried `printf("%s\t%d\n", ptr[i].subject, ptr[i].marks);`. Why didn't it work? Compiler errors?

Comment: I edited your question title which was unintelligible, so I had to guess. If I guessed wrong, feel free to correct it.

Comment: "like `ptr[i]`?" Yes, exactly `ptr[i]`, you should first try it then ask about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ptr->x` is the same as `(*ptr).x`.

`*(ptr + i)` is the same as `ptr[i]`.

Thus, by the transitive property, `(ptr + i)->x` is the same as:

```
ptr[i].x
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the question is how to dereference a pointer to a struct.

Some possible ways:

```
typedef struct
{
    int marks;
    char *subject;
}type;

void foo(type *ptr, ssize_t i)
{
    printf("%s\t%d\n", (ptr + i) -> subject, (ptr + i) -> marks);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", (*(ptr + i)).subject, (*(ptr + i)).marks);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", ptr[i].subject, ptr[i].marks);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", (&ptr[i]) -> subject, (&ptr[i]) -> marks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Indexing with `[i]` is entirely equivalent to adding `i` and dereferencing the address thus produced. The indexing is simply "syntactic sugar", a convenient and customary short form. In fact, the indexing operation is *defined* in terms of adding an offset and dereferencing: `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p+i)`.

One of the more unexpected consequences of defining indexing as addition plus dereferencing is that because addition is commutative (i.e., `p+i == i+p` holds for all p, i), against all appearances indexing is a symmetrical operator, too: for all `p[i]` `i[p]` is a valid, equivalent expression:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // an array of anonymous structs with an int member
    struct { int mI; } arr[] = { {1}, {2}, {3} } ;
    
    // "sizeof arr/sizeof *arr": 
    // dividing the overall size of an array by the size of one element
    // is an idiomatic way to iterate through all elements without caring
    // about the exact count.
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof arr/sizeof *arr; i++)
    {
        // The printed expressions are all equivalent.
        printf( "%i is the same as "
                "%i is the same as "
                "%i is the same as "
                "%i is the same as "
                "%i is the same as "
                "%i\n", 
                arr[i].mI, 
                // Surprising: Indexing is commutative.
                // This may not pass code review, but it's perfectly legal C.
                i[arr].mI,  
                (*(arr + i)).mI,
                (arr + i)->mI,      // short form to access members of structures through a pointer
                (*(i + arr)).mI, // Less surprising: Addition is commutative
                (i + arr)->mI
        );
    }
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o symmetrical symmetrical.c && ./symmetrical
1 is the same as 1 is the same as 1 is the same as 1 is the same as 1 is the same as 1
2 is the same as 2 is the same as 2 is the same as 2 is the same as 2 is the same as 2
3 is the same as 3 is the same as 3 is the same as 3 is the same as 3 is the same as 3
```